# Проблема с парсингом JSON геокодера в JS

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net

необходимо получить координаты по адресу через геокодер из JSON, и всё бы хорошо, но парситься полученный JSON не хочет, выдаёт ошибку. При этом если зайти в инструменты разработчика в Chrome и выполнить скрипт вручную, то всё работает.
Подскажите, кто знает, как решить проблему?

```
 <script src="http://maps.api.2gis.ru/2.0/loader.js?pkg=full" data-id="dgLoader"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;

        DG.then(function () {
            map = DG.map('map', {
                "center": [48.65626, 44.477077],
                "zoom": 10
            });

            var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
            var meetings = document.getElementById('MeetingsInfo');
            var meetingsCount = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('MeetingsCount').innerText);

            for (var i = 0; i < meetingsCount; i++) {
                var req = new XHR();
                req.open('GET', 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(meetings.rows[i+1].cells[0].innerText) + '&format=json');
                req.send(null);
                if (req.responseText != null) {
                    var info = JSON.parse(req.responseText);//здесь ошибка
                    var place = info[0];
                    var lat = Number.parseFloat(place.lat);
                    var lon = Number.parseFloat(place.lon);
                    DG.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map).bindPopup(meetings.rows[i + 1].cells[2].innerText);
                }
            }

            geoclicker = true;
        });
    </script>
```

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Отладка]

UPD: сделал обработку запроса через onload, для первой записи всё обработалось, а на следующей опять ошибка. При этом ещё и не хочет доставать данные из поля таблицы, хотя вручную достаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пример запроса, а лучше ответа добавьте в вопрос

Comment: Где вы ждете ответа от АПИ? Вы в курсе, что XMLHttpRequest запрос асинхронный?

Comment: Послушайте предыдущего оратора и добавьте обработку запроса в функцию `req.onload` или `req.onreadystatechange`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko во фронтенде я ламер, так что могу много нехорошего сделать)

Comment: @Jaxx34 уже сделали. Погуглите про AJAX и асинхронное программирование. Найдите пример использования XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Добавил req.onload и стало работать, спасибо. UPD: не совсем

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил, но заработало не до конца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что я неправильно обрабатывал асинхронный запрос. Так всё заработало:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;

        DG.then(function () {
            map = DG.map('map', {
                "center": [48.65626, 44.477077],
                "zoom": 10
            });

            var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
            var meetings = document.getElementById('MeetingsInfo');
            var meetingsCount = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('MeetingsCount').innerText);
            var meetingsArr = [];

            for (let i = 1; i < meetingsCount+1; i++) {
                meetingsArr.push(meetings.rows[i]);
            }

            meetingsArr.forEach(async (meeting) => {
                var req = new XHR();
                await req.open('GET', 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(meeting.cells[0].innerText) + '&format=json');
                req.onload = function() {
                    if (req.responseText != null) {
                        var info = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                        var place = info[0];
                        var lat = Number.parseFloat(place.lat);
                        var lon = Number.parseFloat(place.lon);
                        DG.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map).bindPopup(meeting.cells[2].innerText);
                    }
                };
                req.send(null);
            }
            );

            geoclicker = true;
        });
    </script>
```